# Need to get server name out of path with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a some VMware server tools that return a string from our VMware servers of all the virtual machines it is hosting. I am using Ruby and need to get all the hostnames, however, when I do, the string looks like this:

```
=>"/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/server1.vmx"
```

Is there a regex to replace the string with what is between the last "/" and ".vmx"?

Comment: This is actually a little ambiguous. Do you want to replace the entire string with the `server1` part, or do you want to replace the `server1` part?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 sweet methods for this.

```
string = "/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/server1.vmx"
File.extname(string) # => '.vmx'
File.basename(string, File.extname(string)) # => "server1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `regex` you can do this with `gsub` or `sub`:

```
s = '=>"/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/server1.vmx"'
result = s.gsub(/(?mi)(=>".+\/)(.+)(\.vmx")/, '\1new\3')
```

**Result**:

```
=>"/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/new.vmx"
```

Comment: Don't use `gsub` for something that should occur once. Even if the match can occur only once, `gsub` will still continue trying to match, making it slower. If a single replacement is needed specify `sub`.

Comment: @theTinMan, Yes, but what if the string is in a huge list with others like it?

Comment: A string isn't a list, nor is a path. `gsub` and `sub` only work on strings. *IF* multiple sub-strings need to be changed then `gsub` would be appropriate, but that's not what the OPs example and question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about using a regex. Ruby has methods that make this easy:

```
path = "/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/server1.vmx"
dir, basename = File.split(path)
File.join(dir, 'foo' + File.extname(basename)) 
# => "/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/foo.vmx"
```

Regular expressions are powerful but that power comes at a price:

- They can be hard to maintain, especially as they become more complex.
- They can really eat up CPU time, especially when they do the wrong thing or aren't explicit enough.
- They can open up logic-holes resulting in bad results, so we have to test them carefully.

Your question isn't entirely clear though:

> ...replace the string with what is between the last "/" and ".vmx"?

could mean you want to replace the entire path with the basename minus the extension:

```
path = File.basename(path, File.extname(path)) 
# => "server1"
```

Comment: How would this handle a filename such as `sub.server1.vmx`, `sub-server1.vmx`?

Comment: It falls apart with the first, but that's not what the OP specified. We work against the requirements. It succeeds with the second.

Comment: Nah I don't think it falls apart...it's hard to tell what the OP is asking exactly. I wasn't criticizing, just curious more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
string = "/vmfs/volumes/d9a12362-2cc7sfe/server1/server1.vmx"
new_string = string.split("/")[-1].gsub(".vmx","")
```

This way you dont need to use regex